# Issues with Component Retrieval in C++ ECS Implementation

Tags: c++, oop, lifetime, unordered-map

I'm working on an Entity-Component-System (ECS) for a game engine in C++, but I've run into a couple of issues related to component management within entities. My **Entity** class stores components in a **std::unordered_map** using **std::type_index** as keys for type-safe component retrieval. Here's a simplified version of my **Entity** class:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <typeindex>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdexcept>

class Component {};

template<typename T>
class ComponentT : public Component {
    // Component implementation
};

class Entity {
  std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::shared_ptr<Component>> m_Components;

public:
  template<typename T, typename... Args>
  void AddComponent(Args&&... args) {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value, "T must be a Component.");
    m_Components[std::type_index(typeid(T))] = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  template<typename T>
  void RemoveComponent() {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value, "T must be a Component.");
    m_Components.erase(std::type_index(typeid(T)));
  }

  template<typename T>
  T& GetComponent() const {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value, "T must be a Component.");
    auto it = m_Components.find(std::type_index(typeid(T)));
    if (it != m_Components.end())
      return *std::static_pointer_cast<T>(it->second);
    throw std::runtime_error("Component not found.");
  }

  template<typename T>
  bool HasComponent() const {
    return m_Components.find(std::type_index(typeid(T))) != m_Components.end();
  }
};
```

I'm encountering two main issues:

1. **Component Not Found Error**: Even after successfully adding a **Mesh** component to an entity, attempts to retrieve it in the rendering system throw a "Component not found" error. Debugging shows that **m_Components** is empty at the time of retrieval, suggesting the component was either not added properly or was somehow removed.
2. **Performance Concerns**: I'm worried about the potential overhead of using RTTI (**typeid** and **std::type_index**) for component retrieval, especially in performance-critical parts of the engine like the rendering loop.

Questions:

How can I ensure that components added to an entity are reliably retrievable later in other systems of the ECS?
Are there more efficient, possibly RTTI-free, ways to implement type-safe component retrieval in a C++ ECS?

Any advice or alternative approaches to improve the reliability and performance of my ECS implementation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your use of shared_ptr combined with disappearing unordered_map entries might be because you're operating on the container from different threads - you're not doing any locking around your container operations.  It's also possible that you're adding multiple elements of the same type (e.g. two Mesh components), not realising that the second replaces the first in the hash table, such that if you erase once there's none left.  But, it's hard for anyone else to say when you haven't given us a complete (but minimal) program that reproduces the issue....